# Playing audio in popup.html using the addEventListener for click?

Tags: javascript, audio, google-chrome-extension

I would like the popup.html to play a sound from a file when a user clicks on an image and stop the sound when the user clicks the same image again.

When I use the code below, the sound begins playing the moment the popup.html is opened and not by the 'addEventListener'.

options.js

```
var eggAudio = new Audio("sound.mp3");
eggAudio.loop = true;
document.getElementById('egg1').addEventListener('click', eggAudio.play() );
```

popup.html

```
<div id='egg'><img id="egg1" src='img/egg.png'/></div>
<script src="options.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second parameter should be a function that gets called when you trigger a click event. With the code you've written, `eggAudio.play()` gets called immediately. You might want to write it like this:

```
document.getElementById('egg1').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
     if (eggAudio.paused) {
       eggAudio.play() 
     } else {
       eggAudio.pause() 
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I see it now. Will I then be required to use jquery to make a toggling click event for play/stop or is there a simpler js way? ie. Click to play, click again to stop.

Comment: Check my latest edit, it's a basic if/else. No jQuery required.